# Javascript inside jquery-modal does not work - Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

I use https://jquerymodal.com/ package for modal dialogues, it works out great when I am in need of editing small forms, which I embed in the same document.

But issue is; I also use jquery-ui-datepicker and  Chosen package (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for my forms. It seems that javascript does not work inside modal.

As noted on jquerymodal.com, i have tried both using embedded in html and ajax loading as below. I couldn't get it working. Below route returns a view where I have a form partial. (I tried with extending layout a file, where I have proper links to my js files..., this didn't work either).

```
        <a href="{{route('form_edit',['projectid' => $project->id])}}" rel="modal:open">
        Load Edit Form
        </a>
```

Is this possible or should i be trying out something different for this?

Comment: It does  but you need to load all javascript libraries on the base page. For example, I use modals to show google map locations. There is no way to load gmaps.js dynamically in requested modals. The reason is that a page can only be done loading once. You can manipulate variables in a dynamic modal, but you can't load js libraries.

Comment: Not all js are compatible with each other, plus many of them has the same "name" convention. therefore things usually becomes intertwine so often so they are conflicted. why don't you use purely css modal. you can take a look here. https://codepen.io/akzhy/details/rRZEmW

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I thought that since I was AJAX(not embedding in current page) loading through a new  route via controller, which renders a new full view with proper heading etc. Which means it would be the new base page.  So  I guess I will try to find another work around.

Comment: Most libraries are triggered by a `$(document).ready()` or `window.onload` state. A modal is an overlay on an existing page. Sure you can render full views in laravel and send them through json. Having libraries loaded that may not be used is not a big deal as the browser caches them. This includes this stackoverflow page.